# stdout and need to flush it C++

Tags: c++, stdout, flush

I have some C++ code that uses `cout` statements for debug purposes and for some reason I can't get all the data to print unless I do a `std::cout.flush();` at the end.

I don't quite understand why this flush operation is needed.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::cout won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858262/stdcout-wont-print)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To add to the other answers: your debugging statements should instead go to `cerr`, because:

- it writes to the standard error, which means that, running the application, you can easily separate the "normal" program output from the errors/debug information via redirection;
- most importantly, `cerr` by default is ***unbuffered***, which means that, after each output operation, it will automatically flush itself, and in general this is desirable for errors and debug output.

(source: C++ standard, §27.3.1 ¶4-5, §27.4.2.1.2 table 83)

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember this for future reference, I normally don't care since I'll remove my cout statements but this project has been one royal pain. I hate third party code.

Answer (score 13):

Are you using `std::endl` to terminate your lines.  This should be the
usual practice, until performance issues require otherwise, but for some
reason, I see a lot of code which uses `'\n'` instead.

Otherwise, you can always do:

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::unitbuf );
```

as one of the first things in `main`.  This will cause a flush at the
end of every `<<`, which is more than you need, but for diagnostic
output to the console, is probably quite acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I do as a habit, but some of the code I'm integrating does not and it's rather large for me to "correct" it..

Comment: @Dixon Steel I know the feeling.  That's why I offered the second suggestion, using `unitbuf`.

Comment: Why should `std::endl` be usual practice?

Comment: @9769953 Because it simplifies debugging. (Obviously, it all the program is doing is outputting large amounts of text, you'll want to optimize by using `\n`. But that should be thought of as an optimization, not as default behavior when performance doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 4):

Is the data that isn't automatically getting flushed lacking a `\n` at the end? By default, standard out doesn't get delivered until a carriage return is seen.

Comment: If I send an endl it will print as well, but I thought in C++ that is the same as a flush operation?

Comment: The carriage return is used as a "flush point", if you will. Keep in mind that C shares the same underlying I/O as C++ and C lacks endl, however the \n still does the trick. std::endl may in fact force the flush; I'd need to examine its implementation (or hear from someone that has) to be sure.

Comment: This is wrong.  Standard out is *not* line buffered.  Where buffering is involved, `iostream` works considerably differently than `FILE`.  `std::cout` will be flushed by an explicit call to `flush` (including that triggered by `std::endl` or by a read on `std::cin`), or at other unspecified times decided by the implementation.  There is no line buffering in `iostream`.

Comment: std::endl _is_ a flush operation, not just a newline. '\n' will not flush, std::endl will flush an iostream.

Comment: OMG! The ones who developing the MinGW version of gdb do not know, that nobody sets the carriage return. Just horrible! My code worked just perfectly on GNU/Linux, but since I run it for Windows®, the prints got messed *only in the gdb, not in plain terminal*. And this became fixed only when I added the `\r` sign. I just have no comments. @Mah, by the way, as I know, the stdout should be flushed not on a «carriage return», but on a «newline».

Answer (score 1):

"When you send output to a stream, it does not necessarily get printed immediately. Rather, it may wait in a buffer until some unspecified event, e.g. buffer full enough, reading from input, or exit from program. The details may vary."

http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs070.200109/notes/io.html

Comment: So does this mean output can be unpredictable and I don't really have an error or deadlock on the stream?

Answer (score 1):

It is the right behavior. You probably use `std::endl` that add `\n` and flush the buffer. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/

You need to flush the stream, if you want to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use `endl` formatter with `cout` operator rather then `flush`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of `std::endl` is only valid if you want a return.
Not sure how you would do this if you wanted to flush a command prompt out.

Comment: this post (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386269/why-do-you-want-to-avoid-flushing-stdout) seemed to have the solution