# std::cout won't print

Tags: c++, debugging, buffer, iostream, cout

Is there any circumstance when `std::cout << "hello"` doesn't work? I have a C++ program where `std::cout` doesn't seem to print anything, not even constant strings (such as "hello").

Is there any way to check if `cout` is able/unable to open the stream? There are some member functions like `good()`, `bad()`, ... but I don't know which one is suitable for me.

Comment: Ah, buffered-output, though art a heartless and cruel wench.

Comment: In a windowing system, the `std::cout` may not be implemented because there are windows and the OS doesn't know which one of your windows to output to.

Comment: never ever give cout NULL. it will stop to work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Make sure you flush the stream. This is required because the output streams are buffered and you have no guarantee over when the buffer will be flushed unless you manually flush it yourself.

```
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

`std::endl` will output a newline and flush the stream. Alternatively, `std::flush` will *just* do the flush. Flushing can also be done using the stream's member function:

```
std::cout.flush();
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Since when does sending just a newline char to a formatted output stream force a flush? I thought the standard was not content-aware about flushes, relying on members (`flush()`) and manipulators (`endl`) to trip a stream buffer flush? Has it been like this since a specific C++ standard?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That doesn't flush the buffer (or shouldn't: on some implementations it does).

Comment: Please post the group of statements containing the std::cout

Comment: @WhozCraig I have not read anywhere but I tried sometime like this. Its worked.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Then if it does flush on your implementation, it does so outside the standard. It it isn't guaranteed to on all implementations. If you want a guaranteed newline+flush, you need `std::endl` or append a `\n` and then invoke one of a number of members that will trip a flush. Just appending text with a `'\n'` won't be guaranteed by the standard to do it alone.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually in the makefile I wrote -O3. In this mode we can not debug the code, so the cursor in the IDE malfunctioned. As a result the cout didn't write immediately even with flush. The flush is now fine. Thanks

Comment: For completeness only (sftrabbit's proposed solutions are better), but you can call `std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf( NULL, 0 );` to turn off buffering.  Or you can do `std::cout << std::unitbuf` to activate unit buffering.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan in Linux/Unix world \n works fine, but in windows/DOS `\n\r` or `\r\n` flush the system that is why it is good idea to use std::endl which does exactly that

Comment: i have the same issue with @mahmood. But for me nothing seems to work. I am using windows 11, and run the executable in powershell. When the programm meets the line with the << operator it exits. Even with a simple  `std::cout<< "hello" << endf;` it stops

Comment: Am using gcc compiler. Added "-static" flag and it worked. See [this so ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789865/1977871)

Answer (score 19):

`std::cout` won't work on GUI apps!

**Specific to MS Visual Studio**:
When you want a console application and use MS Visual Studio, set project property "Linker -> System -> SubSystem" to Console. After creating a new Win32 project (for a native C++ app) in Visual Studio, this setting defaults to "Windows" which prevents `std::cout` from putting any output to the console.

Comment: More specifically, you need OutputDebugString.

Comment: One also needs to add "_CONSOLE" in "C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions", as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19406695/13279557

Comment: @rodrigocfd: OutputDebugString() is unrelated to std::cout. OutputDebugString() is a completeley different device than console in Windows. std::cout goes to the classic text console (DOS prompt), while OutputDebugString() goes to a debug port that Windows applications can hook in like the MS Visual Studio IDE. Using MS Visual Studio the difference between std::cout and OutputDebugString() might not become obvious because both outputs will display in the "output" log view.

Comment: Edit: In MS Visual Studio the std::cout outputs will not display in the "output" log view. (While I was typing my comment above, I pressed ENTER by mistake which sent the unfinished comment without any question. Editing was not possible 5 minutes after. How can I changes these Stackoverflow settings?)

Answer (score 10):

To effectively disable buffering you can call this:

```
std::setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can call your program and disable output buffering in the command line:

```
stdbuf -o 0 ./yourprogram --yourargs
```

Keep in mind this is not usually done for performance reasons.

Comment: This helped me to fix stdout which stopped printing after some amount (random) of data transferred. flush() did not help there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: very strange, so far I tried std::endl, std::flush, stdbuf, std::setvbuf, still after a while the print to stdout is gone, however I can still interact with the program which means it is running, just the stdout is not displaying

Answer (score 9):

It is probable that `std::cout` doesn't work due to buffering (what you're writing ends up in the buffer of `std::cout` instead of in the output).

You can do one of these things:

- flush `std::cout` explicitly:

  ```
  std::cout << "test" << std::flush; // std::flush is in <iostream>
  ```

  ```
  std::cout << "test";
  std::cout.flush(); // explicitly flush here
  ```

  ```
  std::cout << "test" << std::endl; // endl sends newline char(s) and then flushes
  ```
- use `std::cerr` instead. `std::cerr` is not buffered, but it uses a different stream (i.e. the second solution may not work for you if you're interested in more than "see message on console").