# I'm getting different behaviors for break in VS code and VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, break

```
int main() {
  int y = 8;
  int x = 4;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (x == 4) {
      if (y == 7) {
        break;
      }
    }
    cout << "hey";
    y -= 1;
  }
}
```

The above code is code I wrote to test `break` in VS code. It's really weird because I got different behaviors in VS code and VS.
In VS studio, `break` works as expected: the first run, `y != 7` so we don't break and we print out `"hey"`. Then, `y == 7` and we break the loop, so we end up with just 1 `"hey"`. When I copy pasted this code into VS code on the other hand, `break` literally does nothing. I have no idea why.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Maybe you need to flush the output.

Comment: Yah you should try with `std::cout << "hey" << std::endl` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858262/stdcout-wont-print, or you might just need a `std::cin.get()` at the end to _see_ the output

Comment: Does the program keep running, or does it exit (and a normal exit, or a signal or something)? If it exits normally, it's guaranteed by the standard to flush output as part of calling certain destructors.

Comment: Text output to the console that doesn't end in a newline does not necessarily get displayed. Try `std::cout << "hey\n";` and see if that changes things. (Yes, that's similar to what @Tas says, the key difference being that a flush, which is what `std::endl` does, isn't needed here).