# C++ Not Outputting to Terminal

Tags: c++, terminal

I am learning C++, and am currently stumped at displaying my code on the terminal on Windows 10. I've been following Codecademy, such as this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxHLErBLgI8).

I have written the following file, which is saved as `hello.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried this with the line `std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;`, as recommended here: [std::cout won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858262/stdcout-wont-print).

I seem to have `g++` installed correctly, and running `g++ hello.cpp` creates the file `a` as expected. That file can be run without error, but nothing is printed to the terminal. when I run `a` after.

[image: Image showing no display to terminal...]

The same thing happens with PowerShell (using `./a.exe`), or if I put the file in a different directory. I set up VS Code with C++, following this Codecademy [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKCYP4HWisE), and the same issue there.

I feel like I'm maybe not giving enough information tomake this a good question, but I'm not sure what else to say!

Additionally, I set up a project using Code::Blocks and copy+pasted my file there. It has a "run and compile" option, which works fine, displaying the expected text

Comment: Try flushing explicitly `std::endl` [std::cout won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858262/stdcout-wont-print)

Comment: try running your app in a debugger, i think your application is constantly segfaulting on startup due to a dll issue with your installation.

Comment: @user12002570 Sorry, what does "flushing" mean? I tried changing the line to `std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;`, saving, recompiling and then running. But, the same happened: no output to the terminal. Edit: ah, sorry, I see you have editted your comment, but my understanding was correct anyway?

Comment: for a beginner setting up g++ on windows and using the terminal to build and run the program can occasionally be too difficult. Just use Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code, that's a different product). It's a full C++ IDE and compiler package, beginner friendly, everything works out of the box (including debugging), no configuration necessary, it's free and is widely used.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Do you mind explaining what a debugger is? I'm only just starting with C++! It was going ok, following basic tutorials, but then this just doesn't seem to work...

Comment: If you try to learn C++, learn how to build on the terminal, how to debug and how to configure a debugger for g++, all whilst not having any prior knowledge and without a professor or a knowledgeable friend you will rightfully feel overwhelmed. Just use Visual Studio so that you can focus on C++.

Comment: at this point i wouldn't recommend visual studio code, as even setting up a debugger in that is a drag, i would either recommend visual studio or code blocks, they are both a C++ ide that are pre-configured to work out of the box, with visual studio being more widely used in real world with msvc, and code blocks being more used in teaching courses, as it simplified working with g++, until you are at least familiar with how a debugger works and how to setup a complex build environment.

Comment: @bolov I already have "Code::Blocks" installed from a different tutorial. I guess I can just use that whilst learning. But, I did kind of want to be able to run basic things on the terminal...

Comment: @AhmedAEK Ok, cool, thanks. I already have Code::Blocks from another tutorial. I'll just use that. It's a shame that part of the Codecademy "Learn C++" course includes doing it on the terminal... but that there seem to be issues with that, and it's not just as simple as following their instructions

Comment: okay, now i understand what's happening, you have installed both code blocks and mingw separately and added them to PATH and they have a different standard library dll versions, and your apps are segfaulting on startup, i would seriously recommend uninstalling one of them and removing it from PATH.

Comment: I am not saying you shouldn't learn how to build yourself from the terminal. I am saying you shouldn't learn it all at once. First learn basic C++ then you can explore the terminal and setting up compilers and PATHS and so on.

Comment: @user24601 Do give an update if uninstalling one of them and removing the same from PATH solves the iseeu so that future readers can help from it.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm not keen to uninstall the thing that I have working to test if something else works, in case Code::Blocks then doesn't work on resintall! (I'll use Code::Blocks, rather than terminal, whilst learning, for the reasons @bolov suggests). I've already sunk quite a lot of time into this, which is seriously sapping my motivation to learn C++. So, I'll just stick with Code::Blocks and carry on with learning C++!

Comment: @AhmedAEK I did this today. Unfortunately, it still didn't work. Currently installing Visual Studio...